# Sharepoint 2010: Sign-out even after browser closes doesn't sign the user out

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I sign out of Sharepoint 2010, I close my browser.  When I attempt to go back to sign-in, I see that I am already signed in.  All of my browser instances are closed.  This is using Windows Authentication, but I usually have to sign-in when logging in for the first time to my machine or deploying a webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I see a question here.

What I believe is occurring is SharePoint is delivering a cookie to your browser that is authenticating you.  To test, you can go into your browser settings and delete your cookies and then try to access the site again.

Comment: That seems to be true, even though I removed the specific "Sharepoint-KeepSessionAuthenticated" cookie, clearing all cookies seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

go to **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\potrt number**

```
<script runat="server">

    void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ReissueCookie = true;
        e.SessionToken.IsPersistent = false;
    }

    </script>
```